# Eclipse oddity trying to call Rust from Python using PyO3

Tags: python, eclipse, rust, process, pyo3

I'm following the PyO3 Guide and have so far got to chapter 2, [Python modules](https://pyo3.rs/main/module). OS is W10.

I am entering all commands using the CLI outside Eclipse and just using the latter to edit files. NB the Rust add-on, Corrosion, provides some "intellisense" for Rust, and syntactical highlighting. I *could* use an ordinary text editor if I can't solve this issue.

I've managed to get python modules created, but a funny thing happens: when I call `maturin develop` for a second time I get "Caused by: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

On inspection it turns out that this relates to a .pyd file created in the "target" location. I am unable to delete this... until I exit Eclipse. After the restart of Eclipse I can run `maturin develop` again and it concludes OK.

There is nothing obvious to "close down" in Eclipse which I can see. But it appears that some process in Eclipse has been activated and won't shut down. And this is despite the fact that everything is being run from the command line, outside Eclipse.

NB would be interested to know if anyone sees the same thing in Linux.